# how to set pointer back to original state after moving it?

Tags: c

i have this code

```
for(int i =0;i<file_num;i++) {
    int rc =in_file(file_name[i],argv,1,argc);
    if (rc ==0)
    *eligible_file++ =file_name[i];
}
```

so after each iteration,eligible_file is pushed up by 1.Is there any fast way that can return the pointer(after the for_loop) to its original state(before the for_loop), without having to put the loop inside a function?

Comment: Copy the pointer to another pointer and use that copy in the loop?

Comment: Use another indexer: `eligible_file[j++] =file_name[i];`?

Comment: shit i was having a brainfart when asking this question.

Comment: @VanTeoLe Happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<type> * tmp = eligible_file;
for(int i =0;i<file_num;i++){
    int rc =in_file(file_name[i],argv,1,argc);
    if (rc ==0)
    *eligible_file++ =file_name[i];
}
eligible_file = tmp;
```

But I would recommend this instead:

```
<type> * tmp = eligible_file;
for(int i = 0, i<file_num;i++){
    int rc =in_file(file_name[i],argv,1,argc);
    if (rc ==0)
    *tmp++ =file_name[i];
}
```

Comment: i dont know why but the second one didnt work.

Comment: it require a ( before type

Comment: @VanTeoLe Fixed it